# discord.py and tkinter: Message sending not working

Tags: python, tkinter, discord.py, python-asyncio

Here is my code

```py
import threading
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
import asyncio

activity = discord.Game(name="/help")
def get_prefix(client, message):
  with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)

  return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix,
                      intents=discord.Intents.all(),
                      case_insensitive=True,
                      activity=activity,
                      status=discord.Status.online)


async def send_message_to_specific_channel(message,id):
  channel = client.get_channel(id)
  await channel.send(message)

def talk():
  text = text_to_say.get('1.0', tkinter.END)
  ID = input('ID: ')
  asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_message_to_specific_channel(text,ID),client.loop)

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
tkinter.Button(root, text='Talk', command=talk).pack()
text_to_say = tkinter.Text(root)
text_to_say.pack()

def Run_bot():
  client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))

t = threading.Thread(target=Run_bot)
t.start()

root.mainloop()
```

I put in the ID, but nothing happens. Is there something I'm missing?

By the way, most of this code is from StackOverflow.

I am trying to use it on a private channel with permission to read and chat in the channel, if that helps

Comment: See [ask]. Do a preliminary debugging by yourself. Why are you calling ```input()``` in a Tkinter GUI application?.

Comment: @relent95 I am using input() because it wasn't letting me put numbers in a textbox

Comment: No, you shouldn't use ```input()```. It blocks your GUI. Use the ```tkinter.Entry```. There are tones of tutorials. Just google it.